# If $X_1 + X_2 = z$ what is $E[X_1]$?

Tags: probability, statistics

With all variables iid, according to the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508465/conditional-expectation-of-random-variable-given-a-sum) the answer is $\frac{X_1 + X_2}{2}$. However when I perform the following manipulations I get a different answer:

$$E\big[X_1 | X_1 + X_2 = z\big] = \\ E\big[X_1|X_1 = z - X_2\big] =
\\ E\big[z -X_2\big] = \\
z - E\big[X_2\big]
$$

which is not the same thing. This also leads to some odd behavior, such as the expected value of the first of two dice when their sum is $2$. The manipulations above suggest it would be negative.

Comment: You cannot "drop the condition" on the third line - it should be $E[X_1|X_1 + X_2 = z]  = E[z - X_2|X_1 + X_2 = z] = z - E[X_2|X_1 + X_2 = z]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E[X_1 \mid z]= E[z-X_2\mid z]=z-E[X_2 \mid z]$

Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid random variables, generated from the same distribution:

$E[X_1 \mid z] = E[X_2 \mid z]$

By substituting and rearranging:

$E[X_1 \mid z] = E[X_2 \mid z] = \frac{z}{2}$

The error in your answer is that you cannot drop the condition on $X_2$ in your final expression.

Answer (score 0):

As BGM commented, you cannot simply "drop the condition".   After all you can only make the substitution while under that condition.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E[X_1\mid X_1+X_2=z] &=\mathsf E[z−X_2\mid X_1+X_2=z]\\[1ex]&=z−\mathsf E[X_2\mid X_1+X_2=z]\end{align}$$

Then we argue that because the random variables have identical distributions, therefore by symmetry it should hold that $\mathsf E[X_2\mid X_1+X_2=z]=\mathsf E[X_1\mid X_2+X_1=z]$.

$$\mathsf E[X_1\mid X_1+X_2=z] = \dfrac z2$$

And hence$$\mathsf E[X_1\mid X_1+X_2]=\dfrac{X_1+X_2}{2}$$