# How can I prove the following conditional Expectation?

Tags: conditional-expectation, martingales

A sequence of rv $X_{n}$ i.i.d for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $S_{0}=0$ and $$S_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$$.

If $k \leq n$ then $$\mathbb{E}[S_{k}|S_{n}] = \frac{k}{n}S_{n}$$

I am thinking that:

$$\mathbb{E}[S_{k}|S_{n}] = \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k} \frac{P(X=k)|(P(n-k=n-k)) }{P(n=n)} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k} \frac{k \cdot 1}{n}= \frac{k}{n}S_{n}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By linearity, it suffices to show that $\mathsf{E}[X_i\mid S_n]=S_n/n$ for each $1\le i\le n$. However, the latter equality holds because $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are exchangeable r.v.s. (See, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508465/conditional-expectation-of-random-variable-given-a-sum) for details.)

Comment: So you are saying that : \begin{align*}\mathbb{E}(X_k\mid S_n) &= \tfrac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb{E}(X_k\mid S_n) &&\text{Symmetry, }\forall j\in\{1..n\}\\
& = \tfrac 1n\mathbb{E}(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\mid S_n) \\ 
&= \tfrac 1n \mathsf E(S_k\mid S_n) \\
& = \tfrac kn S_n  \\
\end{align*}

Comment: @Mr.Podilatis No. $\mathsf{E}[S_k\mid S_n]=\sum_{i=1}^k\mathsf{E}[X_i\mid S_n]=\sum_{i=1}^k S_n/n=kS_n/n$.

Comment: if now $$M_{k} = \frac{S_{n}-k}{n-k},k=0,1,\dots,n-1$$ how can I show that $$\mathbb{E}[M_{k+1}|M_{0},\dots,M_{k}] =M_{k}$$

Comment: @Mr.Podilatis Are you sure that $M_k$ is defined that way?

Comment: $$M_{k} = \frac{S_{n-k}}{n-k},k=0,1,\dots,n-1$$ how can I show that $$\mathbb{E}[M_{k+1}|M_{0},\dots,M_{k}] =M_{k}$$

Comment: Don”t know how to do it mate.any help?

Comment: @Mr.Podilatis Ok. Just use the previous result: $\mathsf{E}[S_{n-k-1}\mid S_{n-k}]=\frac{n-k-1}{n-k}S_{n-k}$.